# Use deep-first-search. Find out all the articulation points and biconnected components. Show the change process of Low[v] for each node

Tags: depth-first-search

Given the following undirected graph G = (V, E). Using vertex s as the source vertex.
If multiple neighbors are available, visit them using alphabetical order.
[image]

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know hou to find out the low value of each node, thank you.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share how this is related to programming

Comment: **_I don't know hou to find out the low value of each node_** what do you mean by low value of each node ?  Please [edit] the post and clarify your question.